# Terser Coloring of a LogCat Message?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

To speed up my debugging, I color certain messages for instant spotting, like this:

```
if (isOK)
    Log.i(TAG, stringVarContentOfMessage);
else
    Log.v(TAG, stringVarContentOfMessage);
```

It works, but viewing this source code over and over again, where the only justification for occupying 4 precious lines is one different character only (Log.i vs. Log.v) is an eyesore for me.

Any suggestions for avoiding this eyesore *without* resorting to the following?

```
isOK ? Log.i(TAG, stringVarContentOfMessage) : Log.v(TAG, stringVarContentOfMessage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Log.println()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#println%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Log.println(isOK ? Log.INFO : Log.VERBOSE, TAG, stringVarContentOfMessage);
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I knew about Log.x() but I didn't know about `Log.println()`. Accepted +1.

Answer (score 3):

Create a helper method:

```
private void conditionalLog(boolean flag, String tag, String message);
```

Comment: I'd say it shouldn't be private, it should be public and static, otherwise access to it will be limited to just one class.

Comment: @scompt.com That's a good solution but it requires adding a method (which is fine when there isn't any other shortcut). +1.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to color from the other end. Just color selected logcat messages. See: [Modifying the Android logcat stream for full-color debugging](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/) That is a Python script that you can easily mod to your own pleasure.